# Problem with coding for exporting Excel Range (+30 Rows) to Word Table (6x6)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to export a named Range (Dynamic) into a Word Document Table(1). I am able to do this with the code below (I modified but the guts is not my own).

In Word I have created one 1x1 table (for vaDataTbl1) and two 6x6 tables (for vaDataTbl2&3). The two problems I have are 1) If data in ranges vaDataTbl1,2 or 3 are larger than the table, it only fills the first column with no indication that there was more information. I realize I do not have error checking in there (not sure how or where to put correctly), but I would have expected some kind of run time error. 2)I can't determine where to put what to make the information go to column(2) when column(1) is full and column(3) when column(2) is full. The data in vaDataTbl2&3 can vary from 0 to 100 rows. I know I can just make a longer single column table or copy and paste the data to table, but the way I am working with the Word document and the dynamic data from Excel, I would really like to split the exported data.

I am working with: Excel2016 and Word2016, I have made sure the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library (Tools->References) is checked.
I have found and read a previously posted code for exporting (x) by (x) range to a (x) by (x) table and this could be an option if there is not a simple solution to my issues.

```
Sub Export_Table_Data_Word()

'Name of the existing Word document
Const stWordDocument As String = "Data Transfer Testing.docx"

'Word objects.
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdCell As Word.Cell

'Excel objects
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

'Count used in a FOR loop to fill the Word table.
Dim lnCountItems As Long


'Variant to hold the data to be exported.
Dim vaDataTbl1 As Variant
Dim vaDataTbl2 As Variant
Dim vaDataTbl3 As Variant

'Initialize the Excel objects
Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("WordData")
vaDataTbl1 = wsSheet.Range("A2:A3").Value
vaDataTbl2 = wsSheet.Range("E2:E100").Value
vaDataTbl3 = wsSheet.Range("C2:C53").Value

'Instantiate Word and open the "Table Data Transfer" document.
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path & "\Help Documents\" & stWordDocument)

lnCountItems = 1

'Place the data from the variant into the table 1 in the Word doc.
For Each wdCell In wdDoc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells
    wdCell.Range.Text = vaDataTbl1(lnCountItems, 1)
    lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
Next wdCell

lnCountItems = 1

'Place the data from the variant into the table 2 in the Word doc.
For Each wdCell In wdDoc.Tables(2).Columns(1).Cells
    wdCell.Range.Text = vaDataTbl2(lnCountItems, 1)
    lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
Next wdCell

lnCountItems = 1

'Place the data from the variant into the table 3 in the Word doc.
For Each wdCell In wdDoc.Tables(3).Columns(1).Cells
    wdCell.Range.Text = vaDataTbl3(lnCountItems, 1)
    lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
Next wdCell

'Save and close the Word doc.
With wdDoc
    .Save
    .Close
End With

wdApp.Quit

'Null out the variables.
Set wdCell = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing

MsgBox "The " & stWordDocument & "'s table has successfully " & vbNewLine & _
   "been updated!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: It's difficult when someone with little coding background starts out with a project that is somewhat complicated... As it stands, this question is "too broad" - it would require someone to write a tutorial or just write the code for you, and that's not what Stack Overflow is about. I recommend you break the problem down into "bite sized" pieces. Extract *one part* that's a conceptual problem and trim everything down to just that. One Excel table to Word, for example. You can use the [edit] link below the question to make changes.

Comment: Cindy, Thanks for the response. I will break it down and edit. After thinking about it over the weekend, I have a better idea of what I am looking for and will do some more searching in the forum first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Cindy Meister, question is too broad and options are multiple. 
1st of all it may be worth to work only with significant dynamic data from excel and limit data to significant values by using one of the simple two ways below

```
Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("WordData")
   'assumed there is no significant data below empty row
    vaDataTbl1 = wsSheet.Range("A2:A" & wsSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Value
   vaDataTbl2 = wsSheet.Range("E2:E" & wsSheet.Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row).Value
   vaDataTbl3 = wsSheet.Range("C2:C" & wsSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row).Value

    'assumed all rows below significant is empty
    vaDataTbl1 = wsSheet.Range("A2:A" & wsSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    vaDataTbl2 = wsSheet.Range("E2:E" & wsSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    vaDataTbl3 = wsSheet.Range("C2:C" & wsSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

Further considering **Option 1** as some kind of error checking mechanism you are expecting you may add at

```
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.path & "\Help Documents\" & stWordDocument)


        Dim Diff1 As Long, Diff2 As Long, Diff3 As Long, ErrMsg As String
        ErrMsg = ""
        Diff1 = UBound(vaDataTbl1) - wdDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Count
        Diff2 = UBound(vaDataTbl2) - wdDoc.Tables(2).Rows.Count
        Diff3 = UBound(vaDataTbl2) - wdDoc.Tables(3).Rows.Count
        ErrMsg = ErrMsg & IIf(Diff1 > 0, Diff1 & " Rows could not be exported to Table1 " & vbCrLf, "") _
        & IIf(Diff2 > 0, Diff2 & " Rows could not be exported to Table2 " & vbCrLf, "") _
        & IIf(Diff3 > 0, Diff3 & " Rows could not be exported to Table2 " & vbCrLf, "") _

    lnCountItems = 1
    'Place the data from the variant into the table 1 in the Word doc.
    For Each wdCell In wdDoc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells
        wdCell.Range.Text = vaDataTbl1(lnCountItems, 1)
        lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
    Next wdCell
    If Len(ErrMsg) > 0 Then wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Comments.Add wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range, ErrMsg
```

It will add a Error comment at `table1` `Cell1` 
also it can be added at the last `MsgBox'

```
MsgBox "The " & stWordDocument & "'s table has " & IIf(Len(ErrMsg) > 0, "partially", "successfully") & " been updated! " & _
    vbCrLf & ErrMsg, vbInformation
```

Next comes **Option 2** as adding rows to the table to accommodate all the significant data

```
'Place the data from the variant into the table 1 in the Word doc.
For lnCountItems = 1 To UBound(vaDataTbl1, 1)
If lnCountItems > wdDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Count Then wdDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Add
wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(lnCountItems, 1).Range.Text = vaDataTbl1(lnCountItems, 1)
Next lnCountItems

For lnCountItems = 1 To UBound(vaDataTbl2, 1)
If lnCountItems > wdDoc.Tables(2).Rows.Count Then wdDoc.Tables(2).Rows.Add
wdDoc.Tables(2).Cell(lnCountItems, 1).Range.Text = vaDataTbl2(lnCountItems, 1)
Next lnCountItems

For lnCountItems = 1 To UBound(vaDataTbl3, 1)
If lnCountItems > wdDoc.Tables(3).Rows.Count Then wdDoc.Tables(3).Rows.Add
wdDoc.Tables(3).Cell(lnCountItems, 1).Range.Text = vaDataTbl3(lnCountItems, 1)
Next lnCountItems
```

as **Option 3** I would prefer to adjust the data into Columns and rows (added if required).  the full code would be something like

```
Sub Export_Table_Data_Word()

'Name of the existing Word document
Const stWordDocument As String = "Data Transfer Testing.docx"

'Word objects.
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdCell As Word.Cell

'Excel objects
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

'Count used in a FOR loop to fill the Word table.
Dim lnCountItems As Long


'Variant to hold the data to be exported.
Dim vaDataTbl1 As Variant
Dim vaDataTbl2 As Variant
Dim vaDataTbl3 As Variant

'Initialize the Excel objects
Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("WordData")
'assumed there is no significant data below empty row
vaDataTbl1 = wsSheet.Range("A2:A" & wsSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).Value
vaDataTbl2 = wsSheet.Range("E2:E" & wsSheet.Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row).Value
vaDataTbl3 = wsSheet.Range("C2:C" & wsSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row).Value

'assumed all rows below significant is empty
'vaDataTbl1 = wsSheet.Range("A2:A" & wsSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
'vaDataTbl2 = wsSheet.Range("E2:E" & wsSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
'vaDataTbl3 = wsSheet.Range("C2:C" & wsSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value


'Instantiate Word and open the "Table Data Transfer" document.
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.path & "\Help Documents\" & stWordDocument)
'wdApp.Visible = True


Rw = 1
lnCountItems = 1
'Place the data from the variant into the table 1 in the Word doc.
Do While lnCountItems <= UBound(vaDataTbl1, 1)
If Rw > wdDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Count Then wdDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Add
    For Col = 1 To wdDoc.Tables(1).Columns.Count
    wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(Rw, Col).Range.Text = vaDataTbl1(lnCountItems, 1)
    lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
    If lnCountItems > UBound(vaDataTbl1, 1) Then Exit For
    Next Col
Rw = Rw + 1
Loop

Rw = 1
lnCountItems = 1
'Place the data from the variant into the table 2 in the Word doc.
Do While lnCountItems <= UBound(vaDataTbl2, 1)
If Rw > wdDoc.Tables(2).Rows.Count Then wdDoc.Tables(2).Rows.Add
    For Col = 1 To wdDoc.Tables(2).Columns.Count
    wdDoc.Tables(2).Cell(Rw, Col).Range.Text = vaDataTbl2(lnCountItems, 1)
    lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
    If lnCountItems > UBound(vaDataTbl2, 1) Then Exit For
    Next Col
Rw = Rw + 1
Loop

Rw = 1
lnCountItems = 1
'Place the data from the variant into the table 3 in the Word doc.
Do While lnCountItems <= UBound(vaDataTbl3, 1)
If Rw > wdDoc.Tables(3).Rows.Count Then wdDoc.Tables(3).Rows.Add
    For Col = 1 To wdDoc.Tables(3).Columns.Count
    wdDoc.Tables(3).Cell(Rw, Col).Range.Text = vaDataTbl3(lnCountItems, 1)
    lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
    If lnCountItems > UBound(vaDataTbl3, 1) Then Exit For
    Next Col
Rw = Rw + 1
Loop

'Save and close the Word doc.
With wdDoc
    .Save
    .Close
End With

wdApp.Quit


'Null out the variables.
Set wdCell = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing

MsgBox "The " & stWordDocument & "'s table has successfully " & vbNewLine & _
   "been updated!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

All the codes are **tested** with makeshift data. If my understanding of the problem is correct, any further problem, feedback, query is appreciated.

Comment: Ahmed, Thank you for taking the time to look at this. Option 3 did what I was looking for.

Comment: Anderson, you made my day.